# Carpeta para base de datos MySSQLen Tomcat

Tags: mysql, tomcat

Estoy creando una página web (como estudiante) con páginas html/css/jsp y servlets alojados en un servidor Tomcat. (todo en local en mi PC - Windows 7)
Como parte del ejercicio también hay que crear una base de datos MySQL y acceder desde jsp/servlets.

Tengo un par de dudas existenciales que seguro que son falta de conocimientos de como encaja todo, agradecería mucho si alguien me puede aclararlas.https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

1) El fichero de la base de datos está en alguna carpeta específica? No consigo encontrar ningún fichero de las base de datos que creo como prueba desde MySQL.

2) Existe una carpeta específica en Tomcat dónde se deba colocar la base de datos para poder acceder a ella desde el código jsp/servlets?

Gracias

Comment: El fichero estará en tu instalacion de MySQL y da igual donde este pues se accede por ip y puerto.

Comment: Gracias JDev. Sigo un poco perdido pero entiendo que es cuestión de seguir estudiando e intentando hacer código que funcione, de momento mis intentos se cuentan por fracasos.